# the outputs don't update in my shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have problems in my shiny app. all the inputs show the correct response from the server but, when i select the choice 5 in the checkboxgroup the app return the correct thing. but after, when i try other inputs only show the update of box (dyplot1) and the anothers boxes(dyplot2 and prediction) keep static. this is a sample code:

```
  # funciones ----
addDays <- function(data,date,days) {
  for(i in 1:days){
    data[length(data)+1] <- NA
    date[length(date)+1] <- date[length(date)]+1
  }
  y <- xts(data,order.by = date)
  return(y)
}
addDaysForecast <- function(forecast,date,days) {
  data <- rep(NA,length(date))
  for(i in 1:days){
    data[length(data)+1] <- forecast[i]
    date[length(date)+1] <- date[length(date)]+1
  }
  y <- xts(data,order.by = date)
  return(y)
}
plotForecast <- function(table,forecast) {
  days <-length(forecast)
  date <-as.Date(table[,"ENTRYTIME"])
  values <- as.numeric(table[,"CLOSINGPRICE"])
  series <- addDays(values,date,days)
  serieForecast <- addDaysForecast(forecast,date,days)
  day1 <- date[length(date)-days*2]
  day2 <- date[length(date)]+7
  curvas <- cbind(series,serieForecast)
  graf <- dygraph(curvas, main = table[1,1]) %>% 
    dySeries("..1", label = "datos", color = "black") %>%
    dySeries("..2", label = " Forecast",  stepPlot = TRUE, color = "green") %>%
    dyAxis("y", label = "CLOSINGPRICE") %>%
    dyCrosshair(direction = "vertical") %>% 
    dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c(day1, day2)) %>%
    ##dyOptions(maxNumberWidth = 20, stackedGraph = FALSE) %>%
    dyLegend(width = 400) %>%
    dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 3, 
                highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha = 0.2,
                hideOnMouseOut = FALSE) %>%
    dyRangeSelector()
  return(graf)
}
plotNormal <- function(table,thing) {
  date <-as.Date(table[,"ENTRYTIME"])
  values <- as.numeric(table[,thing])
  series <- xts(values, order.by = date)
  ma1 <- xts(runMean(values, n = 6),order.by = date)
  ma2 <- xts(runMean(values, n = 12),order.by = date)
  ma3 <- xts(runMean(values, n = 20),order.by = date)
  mv1 <- xts(runVar(values, n = 6), order.by = date)
  mv2 <- xts(runVar(values, n = 12), order.by = date)
  mv3 <- xts(runVar(values, n = 20), order.by = date)
  ske1 <- xts(movskew(values,6), order.by = date)
  ske2 <- xts(movskew(values,12), order.by = date)
  ske3 <- xts(movskew(values,20), order.by = date)
  curvas <- cbind(series,ma1,ma2,ma3,mv1,mv2,mv3,ske1,ske2,ske3)
  graf <- dygraph(curvas, main = table[1,1], group = "ALL") %>% 
    dySeries("..1", label = "datos", color = "black") %>%
    dySeries("..2", label = "Ma6", color = "red") %>%
    dySeries("..3", label = "Ma12", color = "blue") %>%
    dySeries("..4", label = "Ma20", color = "green") %>%
    dySeries("..5", label = "Mv6",strokePattern = "dashed",axis = 'y2', color = "red") %>%
    dySeries("..6", label = "Mv12",strokePattern = "dashed",axis = 'y2', color = "blue") %>%
    dySeries("..7", label = "Mv20",strokePattern = "dashed",axis = 'y2',color = "green") %>%
    dySeries("..8", label = " as 6",  stepPlot = TRUE, color = "red") %>%
    dySeries("..9", label = " as 12",  stepPlot = TRUE, color = "blue") %>%
    dySeries("..10", label = " as 20",  stepPlot = TRUE, color = "green") %>%
    dyAxis("y", label = thing) %>%
    dyCrosshair(direction = "vertical") %>%
    ##dyOptions(maxNumberWidth = 20, stackedGraph = FALSE) %>%
    dyLegend(width = 400) %>%
    dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 3, 
                highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha = 0.2,
                hideOnMouseOut = FALSE) %>%
    dyRangeSelector()
  return(graf)
}
status <- function(table,forecast) {
  test <- table[nrow(table)-1:nrow(table),]
  last <- test[,"CLOSINGPRICE"]
  if(length(forecast)==1|| forecast==-1 ){
    return(("No se a realizado predicción para este nemo"))
  }else if (last<forecast[1]){
    return(paste("A la alza con precio de cierre: ",forecast[1]))
  }else if(last>forecast[1]){
    return(paste("A la baja con precio de cierre: ",forecast[1]))
  }
}
##skewness moving
movskew <- function(values,n) {
  values2 <- values
  for(i in 1:n){
    values2[i] <- NA
  }
  num <- n
  for(i in 1:(length(values)-n)){
    num <- num + 1
    values2[num] <- as.numeric(skewness(values[i:num]))
  }
  return(values2)
}
whatshow  <- function(array) {
  showthis <- vector()
  for(i in 1:5){
    showthis[i] <- any(array==i)
  }
  return(showthis)
}
getforecast <- function(path) {
  url <- paste0("http://192.168.1.9:3169/api/forecast/", path, "?format=json")
  response <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url)
  if(length(response)>1){
    return(response$forecast)
  }else{
    return(-1)
  }
}
whatPlot <- function(table,name,show,thing) {
  if(show[5]==TRUE){
    fore <- getforecast(name)
    plotForecast(table,fore)

  }else{
    plotNormal(table,thing) %>%
      dyVisibility(visibility=c(show[1],
                                rep(show[2],3),
                                rep(show[3],3),
                                rep(show[4],3)))
  }
}
dyVisibility <- function (dygraph, visibility = TRUE){
  dygraph$x$attrs$visibility <- visibility
  dygraph
}
#creando la tabla de prueba
table <- data.frame(matrix(1, nrow = 100, ncol = 18))
nombres <- c("SYMBOL" ,
             "BOOKING_REF_ID",
             "BIDQTY",
             "BIDPRICE",
             "OFFERQTY",
             "OFFERPRICE",
             "TRADEQTY",
             "TRADEPRICE",
             "OPENINGPRICE", 
             "CLOSINGPRICE",
             "HIGHPRICE",
             "LOWPRICE",
             "VWAPPRICE",
             "IMBALANCE",
             "VOLUME",
             "AMOUNT",
             "TREND",
             "ENTRYTIME")
colnames(table) <-  nombres
table$ENTRYTIME <-seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01", tz="GMT"),
                             as.POSIXct("2015-4-10", tz="GMT"), by="1 day")
# estructura pagina ----
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar( collapsed = TRUE,
                             sidebarMenu(
                               menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
                               menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
                             )
)
body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    # First tab content
    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
            fluidRow(
              column(width = 9,
                     box(title = "Grafico 1", status = "primary", width = NULL,
                         solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                         dygraphOutput("dyPlot1",height = "300px")),
                     box(title = "Grafico 2", status = "primary", width = NULL,
                         solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                         dygraphOutput("dyPlot2",height = "300px"))
              ),
              column(width = 3,
                     box(title = "Inputs", status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, width = NULL,
                         selectInput("var1", 
                                     label = "1) variable",
                                     choices = nombres[3:16],
                                     selected = "CLOSINGPRICE"),
                         selectInput("var2", 
                                     label = "2) variable",
                                     choices = nombres[3:16],
                                     selected = "VOLUME"),
                         checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h3("Ver:"), 
                                            choices = list("Datos" = 1, "Medias" = 2, 
                                                           "Esperanzas" = 3,"Asimetrias"=4, "Forecast"=5),
                                            selected = 1),
                         box(title = "Predicción",status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE,                                                  width = NULL,  
                             verbatimTextOutput("prediction"))
                     ) 
              )
            )

    ),

    # Second tab content
    tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
            h2("Widgets tab content")
    )
  )
)
# app ----
app <- shinyApp(
  #UI
  ui <- dashboardPage(header,sidebar,body),
  server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$checkGroup, {
      #... # do some work
      output$prediction <- renderText({
        forecast <- getforecast("CAMANCHACA")
        status(table,forecast)
      })
      #... # do some more work
    })
    output$dyPlot1 <- renderDygraph({
      show <- whatshow(input$checkGroup)
      whatPlot(table,"CAMANCHACA",show,input$var1)
    })
    output$dyPlot2 <- renderDygraph({
      show <- whatshow(input$checkGroup)
      whatPlot(table,"CAMANCHACA",show,input$var2)
    })

  }
)
# Run the app ----
runApp(app,host="0.0.0.0",port=3838)
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example with all the libraries and functions that are used?

Comment: Also, you could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33048592/5894457) answer, maybe this is the issue you are facing.